# How to get Button element inside several shadow roots of html page by using JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, blockchain, shadow-dom, crypto++

I need to get the button to click on "Claim 1" button on https://bioniq.io/launch/goated-gamer/free-claim using Javascript.

I want to get the Claim button in below screen but the button is hidden hin shadow root of the page

[Here the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCpqu.png)

I tried to use below script to access Claim button but I cannot

```
document.querySelector('bioniq-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('bioniq-launch-sale-main-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('bioniq-launch-sale-header').shadowRoot.querySelector('bioniq-launch-sale-group').querySelector('bioniq-launch-price-option:nth-child(1)').shadowRoot.querySelector('toniq-button').shadowRoot.querySelector('button').click();
```

But it cannot run and return the error. Could you please help to review and advise? Thank you.